# Application on time error ; VBA to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

so basically if I run this piece of code just once it works just fine, and sometimes it works again for a second or a third time,etc... but sooner or later it always gives an error;  ending on this line 'Set ieElement = ieApp.Document.getElementByID("ss-submit")' "Run-time error '424': Object required". Is there anyway to prevent this from happening ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
    Call WriteToGoogleForm  
End Sub 

Sub WriteToGoogleForm()  
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10"), "WriteToGoogleForm" 
    Dim winGas As Double  
    Application.CalculateFull  
    winGas = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value  
    Call UseInternetExplorer(winGas)     
End Sub

Sub UseInternetExplorer(wg As Double)
    Dim ieApp As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.Navigate "www.form.com"

    Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE  
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim ieElement As Object  

    Set ieElement = ieApp.Document.getElementByID("ss-submit")  
    Do While ieApp.Busy  
        DoEvents
    Loop  

    Set ieElement1 = ieApp.Document.getElementByID("entry_106413780")  
    Do While ieApp.Busy  
        DoEvents  
    Loop 

    ieElement1.Value = wg
    Do While ieApp.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ieElement.Click  
    Do While ieApp.Busy  
        DoEvents  
    Loop  

    ieApp.Quit  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the ss-submit element is missing for some reason. Try to add a null validation:

```
Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.Document

If Not IsNull(HTMLdoc.getElementByID("ss-submit"))
```

Comment: thx, this avoids the error, keeping everything nice and working  ; but I still don't understand why it sometimes finds this "ss-submit" and sometimes it doesn't ...

Comment: glad it helped your original question...don't forget to vote! :)

Comment: I assume that your HTML element is generated by server side code and the id changes on the fly?

Comment: I don't think so no, https://docs.google.com/a/airliquide.com/forms/d/1OM1fLW3IMbPxq004W5qvZHDOGIUSc_44tGaU-VOr96s/viewform ; don't know if you can see this, I think you should be able to see this; anyway the id's come from the source code of this webpage and they don't change/ are randomely generated ; or at least I think they don't

Comment: I tried 'HTMLdoc.All("submit")' instead of 'HTMLdoc.getElementByID("ss-submit")' ; but the same problem occurs ...

Comment: I'm leaning at the idea that the document hasn't been fully loaded at the time that the code tried to get the element...have you tried revising your logic here: Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE